# python create a binary search tree using existing function

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm practicing creating a balanced binary search tree in python. 
I already have these below, any idea on how to create a balance_bst funtion that  passed a list of unique values that are
sorted in increasing order. It returns a reference to the root of a well-balanced binary search tree:

```
class LN:
    def __init__(self,value,next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next

def list_to_ll(l):
    if l == []:
        return None
    front = rear = LN(l[0])
    for v in l[1:]:
        rear.next = LN(v)
        rear = rear.next
    return front

def str_ll(ll):
    answer = ''
    while ll != None:
        answer += str(ll.value)+'->'
        ll = ll.next
    return answer + 'None'



# Tree Node class and helper functions (to set up problem)

class TN:
    def __init__(self,value,left=None,right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left  = left
        self.right = right

def height(atree):
    if atree == None:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1+ max(height(atree.left),height(atree.right))

def size(t):
    if t == None:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + size(t.left) + size(t.right)

def is_balanced(t):
    if t == None:
        return True
    else:
        return abs(size(t.left)-size(t.right)) <= 1 and is_balanced(t.left) and is_balanced(t.right)

def str_tree(atree,indent_char ='.',indent_delta=2):
    def str_tree_1(indent,atree):
        if atree == None:
            return ''
        else:
            answer = ''
            answer += str_tree_1(indent+indent_delta,atree.right)
            answer += indent*indent_char+str(atree.value)+'\n'
            answer += str_tree_1(indent+indent_delta,atree.left)
            return answer
    return str_tree_1(0,atree)
```

How do write the balance_bst?

```
def balance_bst(l):
```

Here is what I did:

```
def build_balanced_bst(l):
    if l == None:
        return None
    else:
        middle = len(l) // 2
        return TN(l[middle],
        build_balanced_bst(l[:middle]),
        build_balanced_bst(l[middle + 1:]))
```

It gives me:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: The problem is that if you keep dividing a list in half till there's nothing left, you don't get `None`, you get an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write it for you since that's not what SO is about, but here's the general idea. Since the list is already sorted, the root should be the element in the middle of the list. Its left child will be the root of the balanced tree consisting of the elements to the left of the root in the list, and the right sub-tree will be the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried for a long while and I did not work something out... but I think I'm very close. Do you see where I did wrong?